# display main menu tab content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I click the main tab, it displays the main tab content. When the sub menus are clicked it displays the respective submenu content. But when I click the main menu again after I clicked the sub menu, it is not displaying its main menu content. It is calling the click event but not displaying the content. Below I have attached a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0pmzzp7e/1/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" onclick="clickHome()">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#contact"  data-toggle="tab" onclick='clickContact()'>Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content clear-fix" >
<!-- Home-->
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#home1" data-toggle="tab">Home 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#home2" data-toggle="tab">Home 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content clear-fix" >
           <div class="tab-pane active" id="home-content"> Home Content </div>
           <div class="tab-pane" id="home1"> Home 1 Submenu</div>
           <div class="tab-pane" id="home2">Home 2 Submenu</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Home -->

<!-- Contact-->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="contact">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="submenu">
            <li>
                <a  href="#contact1" data-toggle="tab">Contact 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a  href="#contact2" data-toggle="tab">Contact 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content clear-fix" >
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="contact-content"> Contact Content</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="contact1">Contact1 Content</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="contact2">Contact2 Content</div>
       </div>
   </div>
<!-- End Contact -->
</div>
<script>
    function clickHome(){
        $('#home-content').slideToggle(500);
    };
    function clickContact(){
        $('#contact-content').slideToggle(500);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Did you inspect for errors? In each case your `onClick` events are targeting variables that do not exist.

Comment: @RobertC Yes I tried it is just not showing the content.. otherwise no errors..

Comment: The only thing I see is that the sub-tabs for Home and Contact are retaining their respective `active` state as one would expect.  You're not clearing that when the main tab changes, so when you flip back and forth you're going to see the last active tabs content.

Comment: I edited it to clear the 'active' class. still not working https://jsfiddle.net/0pmzzp7e/6/

Comment: You're removing and adding it to `.nav-tabs` in your code.  The `active` class is applied to the `<li>` as well as the active `.tab-pane`, the latter of which also has an `aria-expanded` that is toggled between false/true.